# Numerical Overflow in Dirichlet Boundary Value Problem On High Dimensional State

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, boundary-value-problem, finite-differences, multigrid

I am using multigrid methods to solve a quasilinear parabolic pde with Dirichlet boundaries.  The problem is too long to reproduce here, but my question is more practical than theoretical:

The state is defined as $\Omega \in \times^4 [0,1]$ and the value of the function at $1$ is infinite in several directions.  This causes numerical overflow in my solution.  Does anyone have suggestions on standard transformations (or better yet reading about them) that can reduce this value? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could head over to https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ and give it a try there.